# Ensuring Sample is on Working Electrode Only of a Biosensor

Tags: sensors

How do I ensure that the sample is growing on the working electrode only?

The goal is to ensure the sample does NOT make contact with reference and counter electrodes or at least ensure minimal contact with those respective electrodes?

My concern is that the sample might spread onto areas other than working electrode, so what are some ways we can address this and make certain that the sample does not over flow or spread onto other areas of the biossensor ？

Comment: What are you talking about?  What sensors, what processor, what software, what language?

Comment: Could you use like a vacuum or a magnetic field or an air pressure system to help isolate it ?  But like Tim said .. your question is so general, who knows?